# crouton gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wundef-prefix=HAVE_,CRAS_'

Tags: chromebook, crouton

whenever I try to install a chroot, it will go fine for about 2 minutes, and then say:

```
Compiling CRAS (i386)...
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wundef-prefix=HAVE_,CRAS_'
Failed to complete chroot setup.
```

Anyone know how to fix this issue ?

there is discussion - https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/4943 but no solve

with fix at https://github.com/iptoux/crouton/tree/9109b631e3d363630b6430d60651fc516b4e8081,

I compile source but not work here is compiled file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VENdY60vIsnVB4AnzKLoHryvwGR-dyhY/view?usp=sharing

I get error

```
sudo crouton -t kde-desktop -r list -n kde 
/usr/local/bin/crouton: 99: .: Refusing to exec /tmp/crouton.Rjb/installer/main.sh from noexec mount; see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/security/noexec_shell_scripts.md
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install it.
[image]

I changed one commands in the steps below.
[debian wiki chroot](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot)

Change

```
debootstrap --arch i386 stretch /srv/chroot/stretch http://deb.debian.org/debian
```

to

```
fakeroot debootstrap --arch i386 stretch /srv/chroot/stretch http://deb.debian.org/debian
```

Comment: sory, I don't understand what are you doing